# How to determine whether PHP password_hash functions supports a 'thread' option?

Tags: php

For the PHP function [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) the manual says that passing the number of threads is "Only available when PHP uses libargon2, not with libsodium implementation.".

An error will be given if the thread option is set when it's not available.

For library code, how can I determine at run-time whether the thread option is available?

Comment: You get an error when you provide a `threads` setting, but it can't be used?

Comment: @JaredFarrish There is no extension; the function is [part of the PHP core](https://www.php.net/manual/en/password.installation.php).

Comment: @Olivier Deleted, if it's not a loaded extension (because it's PHP built with a C library that isn't registered as an extension).

Answer (score 2):

The [`PASSWORD_ARGON2_DEFAULT_THREADS`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php) constant is only defined when libargon2 is used:

> **PASSWORD_ARGON2_DEFAULT_THREADS** Default number of threads that Argon2lib will use. Not available with libsodium implementation.

So you can just test if the constant exists:

```php
if(defined('PASSWORD_ARGON2_DEFAULT_THREADS'))
{
   // Set the number of threads
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the [extension is loaded](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php) and remove the option if not.

```
function hash_password(
    string $password,
    string | int | null $algo,
    array $options = []
): string {
    if (!extension_loaded('libargon2') && isset($options['threads'])) {
        unset($options['threads']);
    }

    return password_hash($password, $algo, $options);
}
```

Comment: Let me know if the loaded extension name is not `libargon2`, I don't know this for sure.

Comment: There is no libargon2 extension. The function is [part of the PHP core](https://www.php.net/manual/en/password.installation.php).

Comment: @Olivier What does this mean? _To enable Argon2 password hashing, however, PHP must be build with libargon2 support using the --with-password-argon2[=DIR] configure option._ Seems like something else is being loaded, although `password_hash()` will work without it.

Comment: If PHP is built without libargon2, the [list of available algorithms](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-algos.php) will not include `argon2i` and `argon2id`.

Comment: What is the argument? That `extension_loaded('libargon2')` won't detect if `libargon2` is loaded?

Comment: There is no PHP extension with the name libargon2. It's just the name of a C library.

Comment: So then building with `--with-password-argon2[=DIR]` is not detectable except by looking for side effects like a constant. Sure, okay (this is probably why I couldn't find the extension specifically). That's not the same as "`password_hash()` is part of core PHP".

Comment: @JaredFarrish There is a libsodium extension, which can provide the argon hash functionality - https://wiki.php.net/rfc/sodium.argon.hash but this is all quite confusing.

Comment: @Danack It definitely seems like a mess; why building with a specific library wouldn't be identified as an extension seems unusual but maybe there's a reason. There is also an extension for PHP Argon2, but it doesn't look like it's really related.

Comment: @Danack I do think the alternate method that unsets based on PHP configuration (however you determine that) is a useful way to implement your library requirement.